# Ionic 2: Place drawer content in multiple views dynamically

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm working with ionic tab template to which I added a navigation drawer. I want the navigation drawer to be available to all the tabs, but I don't want to repeat the markup for the content of drawer in all the tab pages. How do I include this content dynamically (something like php `include()`). Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>Welcome</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons start left>
            <button menuToggle ion-button small icon-only color="royal">
                <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<!-- NAVIGATION DRAWER MARKUP THAT I DONT'T WANT TO REPEAT -->
<!-- STARTS HERE -->
<ion-menu [content]="mycontent">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item small>
                <ion-icon ios="ios-contact" md="ios-contact" item-left></ion-icon> Profile
            </ion-item> <!-- more content -->
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
<!-- ENDS HERE -->
<!-- NAVIGATION DRAWER MARKUP THAT I DONT'T WANT TO REPEAT -->

<ion-nav #mycontent [root]="homePage"></ion-nav>

<ion-content padding>
    <!-- CONTENT OF THE HOME-PAGE -->
</ion-content>
```

This is what the rootPage (HomePage) looks like . . .

Comment: You can put that markup in the `app.html` and it will be available in every page where the `menuToggle` button is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Persistent Menu section here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/Menu/)

You need to set

```
<ion-menu [content]="mycontent" persistent=true>
```

> Persistent menus display the MenuToggle button in the Navbar on all pages in the navigation stack.

It should display for all your tabs unless you dont want to set menu for inner pages.
Sample menu code by ionic [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-preview-app/tree/master/src/pages/menus/basic)
The menu for the entire app is set [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-preview-app/blob/master/src/app/app.template.html)

Comment: I so much hoped it would work but it didn't. Maybe I have not got everything right. More precisely asked is:: where would I put the persistent menu content? and how do I call this content into all the pages?